# ComboBox Event triggers a RadioButton to be checked and populate a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I'm a noob when it comes to XAML and MVVM and am constructing a maintenance screen for our project.  The combobox is populated from a list retrieved from a database.  When a value selected from the combobox is I want to read one of the properties from the selected item, and check 1 of 2 radiobuttons and then populate a listbox using that same selected item.  Here's my xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StatementPrinting.Client.Views.Setup.TestView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:telerikRibbonView="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonView"
         xmlns:examples="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation">
<telerik:RadBusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding BusyDetail.IsBusy}" BusyContent="{Binding}"
                          IsIndeterminate="True"
                          BusyContentTemplate="{StaticResource BusyIndicatorBusyContentTemplate}">
    <!--<Grid MinWidth="650" MinHeight="400">-->
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,5,20">
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18">Report Group Setup</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock>Here you edit whether the selected group is printed or not and what items are part it.</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0">Select a Group:</TextBlock>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbReportGroup" IsEditable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportGroups}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReportGroup}" />
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="40,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Printing?</TextBlock>
                <RadioButton x:Name="printYesRadioButton" Margin="10" GroupName="printRadioButtonGroup" Content="Yes">
                    <RadioButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbReportGroup, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RadioButton.Style>
                </RadioButton>
                <TextBlock Name="Or_TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,10,5,10">or</TextBlock>
                <RadioButton x:Name="printNoRadioButton" Margin="10" GroupName="printRadioButtonGroup" Content="No">
                    <RadioButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbReportGroup, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RadioButton.Style>
                </RadioButton>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <TextBlock>
                    Change the items that belong to this group:
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,5">Current Notices:</TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,5">Available Notices:</TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                <ListBox></ListBox>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
                    <Image Source="c:\_MicrosProjects\StatementPrinting\DEV\StatementPrinting\StatementPrinting.Client\Resources\arrow-left-10.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
                    <Image Source="c:\_MicrosProjects\StatementPrinting\DEV\StatementPrinting\StatementPrinting.Client\Resources\arrow-right-10.png"/>
                </Button>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">
                <ListBox></ListBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
```

The codebehind:

```
using Mbs.Common.Instrumentation;
using Mbs.Mvvm.Core;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events;
using StatementPrinting.Client.ViewModels.Base;
using StatementPrinting.DataLayer;
using StatementPrinting.Domain;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StatementPrinting.Client.ViewModels.Setup
{
    public class TestViewModel : SecurityTabbedWorkspaceViewModelBase
    {
        public TestViewModel(IScreenViewModel screenVM, string connectionString, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            this.SetNameAndTitle("Report Group Setup");
            this.ScreenVM = screenVM;
            this.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            this.AppEventAggregator = eventAggregator;

            this.SetSecurity();
            LoadReportGroups();
        }

        private readonly ObservableCollection<ReportGroup> _ReportGroups = new ObservableCollection<ReportGroup>();
        public ObservableCollection<ReportGroup> ReportGroups
        {
            get { return _ReportGroups; }
        }

        private string _SelectedIndex;
        public string SelectedIndex { get; set; }

        private ReportGroup _SelectedReportGroup;
        public ReportGroup SelectedReportGroup
        {
            get { return _SelectedReportGroup; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedReportGroup = value;

                MessageBox.Show("Print: " + SelectedReportGroup.Print.ToString());
                SetPrintOption(SelectedReportGroup.Print);

                this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedReportGroup");
            }
        }

        private void SetPrintOption(bool PrintOption)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Print 2: " + SelectedReportGroup.Print.ToString());
            if (SelectedReportGroup.Print)
            {
                //printYesRadioButton.IsChecked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //printNoRadioButton.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }

        private void LoadReportGroups()
        {
            try
            {
                CancellationToken cancelToken = this.GetCancellationToken();
                this.BusyDetail.CanBeCanceled = true;
                this.BusyDetail.TurnOnBusyIndicator("Loading...");

                Task<List<ReportGroup>> loadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<ReportGroup>>(() =>
                {
                    using (StatementPrintingContext context = new StatementPrintingContext(ContextConnectionStringHelper.GetEntitiesConnectString(this.ConnectionString)))
                    {
                        return context.ReportGroups.ToList();
                    }
                },
                cancelToken);
                var completedTask = loadTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    if (t.Exception != null)
                    {
                        this.RaiseErrorMessageNotification(t.Exception.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        t.Result.ForEach(r => this.ReportGroups.Add(r));
                        //
                        //    or
                        //
                        //foreach (var r in t.Result.ToList())
                        //{
                        //    ReportGroups.Add(r);
                        //}
                    }
                },
                cancelToken, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.RaiseErrorMessageNotification(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                this.BusyDetail.TurnOffBusyIndicator();
            }
        }

        private DelegateCommand _SaveChangesCommand;
        public DelegateCommand SaveChangesCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_SaveChangesCommand == null)
                {
                    _SaveChangesCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            using (var db = new StatementPrintingContext(ContextConnectionStringHelper.GetEntitiesConnectString(this.ConnectionString)))
                            {
                                // ******Do any database changes here!********
                                // . . .
                                // . . .

                                this.SaveChangesCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                                this.RaiseMessageNotification("Changes saved successfully.");
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            this.RaiseErrorMessageNotification(ex.Message);
                            ExceptionLogger.Instance.WriteExceptionTrace(ex, this.GetType().ToString());
                        }
                    },
                    () =>
                    {
                        // *******Put conditional code here!***********
                        // . . .
                        // . . .

                        return true;
                    });
                }
                return _SaveChangesCommand;
            }
        }


        private DelegateCommand _TestCommand;
        public DelegateCommand TestCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_TestCommand == null)
                {
                    _TestCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            this.TestCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            this.RaiseErrorMessageNotification(ex.Message);
                            ExceptionLogger.Instance.WriteExceptionTrace(ex, this.GetType().ToString());
                        }
                    },
                    () =>
                    {
                        return true;
                    });
                }
                return _TestCommand;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just to reiterate, a person selects an item from the combobox.  When they do that, it reads the print value of that item that is stored in the database and then checks either the "Yes" or "No" radiobutton.  This is the main issue I'm having right now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Property in Your ViewModel named it `SelectedName` and Bind it to SelectedValue of the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbReportGroup" IsEditable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ReportGroups}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReportGroup}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedName}" />
```

and in the ViewModel in the Setter of the SelectedName Property add your code:

```
public string SelectedName
    {
        get { return _SelectedName; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedName= value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedName");

            // do your data retrieving form database ...
            CheckPrintYesOrNow();
        }
    }
```

for the `RadioButton` you can use the same way add a `bool` Property in your ViewModel and bind to.